# Which image transformations are considered continuous transformations?

Tags: image-processing

In the article [J. Matas, O. Chum, M. Urban, T. Pajdla: Robust Wide Baseline Stereo from Maximally Stable Extremal Regions](http://www.google.hr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=matas%20robust%20wide-baseline%20stereo%20from%20maximally%20stable%20extremal%20regions&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcmp.felk.cvut.cz%2F~matas%2Fpapers%2Fmatas-bmvc02.pdf&ei=vbr6T8_EK8HBhAet8NHoBg&usg=AFQjCNGXv1k27m9V0t21Q89ogVqZLvtvYQ) it is stated that:

> The set (of extremal regions) is closed under continuous (and thus perspective) transformation of image coordinates, ...

I know what perspective transformations (and consequently, affine transformations) are, but could anyone give examples of other transformations that fall under the category of *continuous transformations of image coordinates*? How would such transformations be characterized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think "continuous" is meant in the [strict mathematical sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) here, i.e. no abrupt changes in the coordinate mapping.

Most non-rigid image alignment algorithms (try to) produce continuous mappings. Distortion filters in popular photo-editing applications (like [Photoshop's Warp effect](http://csscreme.com/tutorials/photoshop-tutorials/warp_tool_effect_photoshop_tutorial)) are usually continuous mappings, too.

**ADD:** Here are two examples of transformations that are continuous but not affine or perspective:

[How to flatten image label on a food jar](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2406/how-to-flatten-the-image-of-a-label-on-a-food-jar/2409#2409)

[Flatten a sudoku grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196198/how-to-remove-convexity-defects-in-sudoku-square/10226971#10226971)

Comment: Could you give some examples of some of those algorithms please? At least one or two to get me started in the search?